# What times do Hunter Slimes spawn?

Tags: slime-rancher

I'm trying to hunt for Hunter Slimes in version 0.3.5c in the not-so-secret lake area.

[image: Lake area]

Do they spawn at certain times that are more specific than when the sun is set? Also, it mentioned in the code or by the developers anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

The hunter slime wiki page has several tips on catching them

First:

> If you want to catch that slime in the wild, do it at night, since they will be less rare.

Second:

> Because of their masking abilities, you can barely see them sometimes, especially at night. Try looking for their faces, since they are always visible.

And Finally:

> Hunter Slimes make a distinctive sound when they turn invisible. Listening for that sound could help you find one!

So all in all, hunting for these rare slimes at night will increase your chances of finding them, but will make them harder to spot in general due to their ability to turn invisible. Keep your eyes and ears open however, and you should be able to find some.

**Edit:**

No there is no specific time after dark when the hunter slimes spawn rate increases. The following youtube video ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVKSmt5LCQk)) shows an actual location however, which is claimed by multiple users in [THIS](https://www.reddit.com/r/slimerancher/comments/4waj7a/hunter_slime_spawn_location/) reddit post to have a higher or possibly faster spawn rate.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm not looking on tips to catch them, but when they are less rare.

Comment: @Peanut I answered that, the first quote from the wiki page I stated says that you should do it at night because that's when they are less rare.

Comment: From the first version of the original post: "Do they spawn at certain times that are **more specific than when the sun is set?**"

Comment: Check the edit for more info now

Comment: I'm already in that location as seen in my screenshot in the first version of the original post.

Comment: @Peanut: Then happy hunting :)

Comment: It can't be less rare at night when there isn't a set time range.

Comment: @Peanut what do you mean? I'm guessing the set time range for this increased spawn rate is likely the nighttime hours.

Comment: From one of my previous comments in this thread: "From the first version of the original post: "Do they spawn at certain times that are **more specific than when the sun is set?**""

Comment: @Peanut from what I have gathered from the little info available, no there is no specified time window in which the spawn rate of the slimes is increased

Comment: What little info available?

Comment: The little info available when it comes to hunter slimes and their spawn rates

Comment: The code has information

Comment: Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: Everyone has access to Slime Rancher's source code if they have a copy.

Answer (score -1):

If u go to the meadows at night with full fruit meat and veggie the left corner of the map has hunter largo slimes that are feral feed them to get their mineral. Then when u get home u can mix them with another slime. Feeding them also calms them down so they wont attack u afterward.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.